# Is it an illicit interaction if a user reviews a question by an alternate account of the main account in triage or another review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, accounts

Theoretically, what would happen if I created a new account and asked a question, then reviewed it in triage or first-posts with the main account?  Is that an illicit interaction, or is that okay?

Comment: Uber-meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35593/175248

Comment: Clarification:  reviews would count as votes or otherwise interacting with the second account, so it wouldn't be okay.

Comment: If a second account allows you to do something you can't with just one, then, yes, it would be heavily frowned upon.  You clearly have a conflict of interest when interacting with the post.

Comment: Would something that sounds dishonest be dishonest if I did it? In my opinion, no. But if you did it...

Comment: That having said, nobody would probably notice it if you review everything and just happen to come accross your second account's post (i.e., review without caring about the username).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're prohibited from doing anything with an additional account that you couldn't do with your original account.

Since you can't review your own posts with a single account, you cannot use multiple accounts to do so.